# Migrating from SpringFox to OpenAPI (SpringDoc) during JDK 17/SB3 Upgrade - Stuck on @Authorization and @AuthorizationScope Conversion

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, springdoc

Am migrating my API to JDK 17/Spring Boot 3.  I am thus forced to migrate my Swagger from SpringFox to SpringDoc (OpenAPI). I have a SpringDoc @Operation that in its SpringFox legacy form looks like this:

```
@ApiOperation(
   value= "Do XYZ",
   authorizations = {
     @Authorization(
        value = "internalOAuth",
        scopes = {
          @AuthorizationScope(scope = "some_scope_xxx", description = "Xxxxxx"),
          @AuthorizationScope(
              scope = "com.example.class",
              description = "Xxxxxx")
        })
  })
```

Can't find a thing in Google-land or here on SO that says explicitly what needs doing to convert over the @Authorization and @AuthorizationScope annotations.  I know @ApiOperation becomes just @Operation, but that's all.  All the guides and examples seem to have skipped this rather common configuration situation.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Try `@SecurityScheme` and `@SecurityRequirement`: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#security-annotations